# Getting error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." from a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that conditionally sets a variable based on another variable:

```
set LABEL_NAME=main
echo %LABEL_NAME%
set UPLOAD_CHANNELS= 

/E:ON /V:ON if not defined %BINSTAR_TOKEN% set UPLOAD_CHANNELS=--upload-channels scitools/label/!LABEL_NAME!

echo %UPLOAD_CHANNELS%
```

I get the error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

from the line containing the inline `if` statement.

Note that the variable `UPLOAD_CHANNELS` is first defined to equal a single space character.

Comment: `/E:on /V:on` are command line switches. use `setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` instead. put it in one line. guessing that `UPLOAD_CHANNELS` is going to be used later, and as it contains spaces, you'd better `set "UPLOAD_CHANNELS=bla bla bla"`

Comment: With `setlocal ...` and `/E:ON /V:ON` removed I get the error `'UPLOAD_CHANNELS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Surrounding `UPLOAD_CHANNELS=...` in double quotes gives me `The system cannot find the path specified.`...

Comment: You are missing `cmd` in front of `/E:ON /V:ON ...`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your code look like something like this?

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "LABEL_NAME=main"
echo %LABEL_NAME%
set "UPLOAD_CHANNELS= "

if not defined BINSTAR_TOKEN set "UPLOAD_CHANNELS=--upload-channels scitools/label/!LABEL_NAME!"

echo %UPLOAD_CHANNELS%
```

Note that using the `defined` keyword look for variable name not for its content, so no need `%`

I guess your code does something more, at this point there is no need for delayed expansion

Comment: That does the job! Thanks for your help @elzooilogico